# Problems with backbuffer and EndScene hook

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

So, i've been trying to retrieve the backbuffer data using a EndScene hook, the thing is that for some reason my GetBackBuffer is returning a invalid result (i think) because when i use pSurface->GetDesc() it returns that the backbuffer has Width 1 and height 1, and it always return the pBits filled with 0.

```
HRESULT WINAPI hkEndScene(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice)
{
    IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface = 0;
    IDirect3DSurface9* pBBuffer = 0;
    D3DLOCKED_RECT Lock;
    D3DSURFACE_DESC desc;
    if (pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pSurface) != D3D_OK)
    {
        logg << "ERROR GetBackBuffer: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return pEndScene(pDevice);
    }
    pSurface->GetDesc(&desc);
    logg << "Size: " << desc.Width << ", " << desc.Height << endl;
    HRESULT hRes = pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(desc.Width, desc.Height, desc.Format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &pBBuffer, NULL);
    if (hRes != D3D_OK) 
    {
        logg << "ERROR CreateOffscreenPlainSurface: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return pEndScene(pDevice);
    }
    hRes = pDevice->GetRenderTargetData(pSurface, pBBuffer);
    if (hRes != D3D_OK)
    {
        logg << "ERROR GetRenderTargetData: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return pEndScene(pDevice);
    }
    pBBuffer->LockRect(&Lock, NULL, D3DLOCK_READONLY);
    Com.DrawBuffer(Lock.pBits);
    logg << Lock.pBits << endl;
    //Usual free memory functions
    pSurface->Release();
    pBBuffer->UnlockRect();
    pBBuffer->Release();
    return pEndScene(pDevice);
}
```

Comment: You should probably be hooking Present since that's when the program is actually saying it's done rendering to the back buffer.

Comment: That doesnt actually explains why my bug is happening.

Comment: That's because it was never meant to. It's a comment not an answer.